# How to call a BI publisher report from SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, report, soapui, bi-publisher

I am trying to view the data of a BI publisher report from SOAP UI.
I have used SAWSessionService  to establish the connection and as a response I have got a sessionID .

I have again used XMLViewService -> executeXMLQuery to view the report .
I have used the  sessionID that I got earlier , to create the envelope as follows:

```html
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:v7="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v7">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v7:executeXMLQuery>
        <v7:report>
         <v7:reportPath>absolute_report_path
         </v7:reportPath>
         <v7:reportXml></v7:reportXml>
         </v7:report>
         <v7:outputFormat></v7:outputFormat>
         <v7:executionOptions>
            <v7:async></v7:async>
            <v7:maxRowsPerPage></v7:maxRowsPerPage>
            <v7:refresh></v7:refresh>
            <v7:presentationInfo></v7:presentationInfo>
            <v7:type></v7:type>
         </v7:executionOptions>
         <v7:reportParams>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v7:filterExpressions></v7:filterExpressions>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v7:variables>
               <v7:name></v7:name>
               <v7:value></v7:value>
            </v7:variables>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v7:nameValues>
               <v7:name></v7:name>
               <v7:value></v7:value>
            </v7:nameValues>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v7:templateInfos>
               <v7:templateForEach></v7:templateForEach>
               <v7:templateIterator></v7:templateIterator>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <v7:instance>
                  <v7:instanceName></v7:instanceName>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <v7:nameValues>
                     <v7:name></v7:name>
                     <v7:value></v7:value>
                  </v7:nameValues>
               </v7:instance>
            </v7:templateInfos>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v7:viewName></v7:viewName>
         </v7:reportParams>
         <v7:sessionID>session_id_Earlier_Generated</v7:sessionID>
      </v7:executeXMLQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I am getting the response as Path not found .
I have given public permissions to the report .

Can someone please help ?

I feel I am doing something wrong .

Comment: Could you show the path you provided?

Comment: Hi Sherry ,  I used  absolute path .. /shared/Custom/TestReport

Comment: Hi Joe, drop the /shared and use /Custom/TestReport. Example <v2:reportAbsolutePath>/Samples/Financials/Balance Letter.xdo</v2:reportAbsolutePath>

Comment: Hi Sherry , I tried that but didnt work out

Comment: Can you provide the URL (minus the actual domain) that you'd normally go to if you'd access this report through the Interactive login?

Comment: /analytics/saw.dll?bipublisherEntry&Action=open&itemType=.xdo&bipPath=%2FCustom%2FTest12.xdo&path=%2Fshared%2FCustom%2FTest12.xdo

Comment: Why don't you use BI publisher's own web services? Documentation is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22259/reportservice.htm#BIPDV824

Comment: Also I don't think what you are trying to do with OBIEE webservice is even feasible. Use the bi publisher webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute path needs to be based on the directory structure below your Shared Folders.  For spaces in names, a + symbol has always worked for us.  An easy way to find your absolute report path is to find the URL that you'd go to if you just clicked on the report to run it from the interactive menu, and then take the stuff after the xmlpserver:

For example:

http://yourdomainhere:9704/xmlpserver/FolderRepresentingCompanyNameUnderSharedFolders/ManufacturingFolder/Production+Stats.xdo

In this case, your absolute path is: /FolderRepresentingCompanyNameUnderSharedFolders/ManufacturingFolder/Production+Stats.xdo

Comment: Hi I think there is some underlying issue as I dont see any issue with the path name .